# Desencadenadores DML, las tablas inserted, deleted y "updated"

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

He estado usando desencadenadores DML, las tablas inserted y deleted. Pero no encuentro la manera de tener la misma funcionalidad luego de actualizar una tabla. hay alguna manera de hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Que quieres hacer cuando actualizas la información?, sería bueno que edites tu pregunta y agregues el código que quieres hacer cuando actualizas la información.

Comment: Quiero que un trigger se dispare y que inserte en una tabla "Bitacora" la informacion actualizada, para llevar un control de todo lo que se actualiza. @Davlio

Comment: Ahora entiendo tu pregunta, en SQL Server no existe la tabla `updated`. Solo las tablas `inserted` y `deleted.` Puedes revisar: [Usar las tablas insertadas y eliminadas](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms191300(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Ya lo logré. @Davlio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando se ejecuta una operación de actualización (UPDATE) el proceso es similar a una operación de eliminación seguida de una operación de inserción, donde la pseudo-tabla deleted se llena con filas que contienen los datos "antiguos" y la pseudo-tabla inserted se llena con filas que contienen los datos "nuevos".

Para el caso que mencionas:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TriggerName
    ON dbo.TableName
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Bitacora (Col1, Col2)
    SELECT i.ColA, i.ColB FROM inserted i;
END
GO
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Exactamente la explicación y el ejemplo que necesitaba.